# Could not determine access type for property "file"

Tags: symfony

I have a little problem with my image upload, can u help me please:

> Could not determine access type for property "file".

**Controller**

```
/**
 * Creates a new Produits entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Produits();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('adminProduits_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('EcommerceBundle:Administration:Produits/layout/new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Produits entity.
 *
 * @param Produits $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Produits $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ProduitsType::class, $entity);

    $form->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Ajouter'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Produits entity.
 *
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Produits();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return $this->render('EcommerceBundle:Administration:Produits/layout/new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**Form**

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('file', FileType::class, array('data_class' => null))
    ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Ecommerce\EcommerceBundle\Entity\Media'
    ));
}
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'ecommerce_ecommercebundle_media';
}
```

**Entity**

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name",type="string",length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $path;

/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1024k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpg", "image/bmp"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PDF"
 * )
 */
public $file;

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __dir__.'/../../../../web/uploads';
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getAssetPath()
{
    return 'uploads/'.$this->path;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    $this->oldFile = $this->getPath();
    $this->updateAt = new \DateTime();

    if (null !== $this->file)
        $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(),true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(),$this->path);
        unset($this->file);

        if ($this->oldFile != null) unlink($this->tempFile);
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function preRemoveUpload()
{
    $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if (file_exists($this->tempFile)) unlink($this->tempFile);
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return String
 */
public function setPath($path)
{
    $this->path = $path;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set alt
 *
 * @param string $alt
 * @return String
 */
public function setAlt($alt)
{
    $this->alt = $alt;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return String
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set updateAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updateAt
 *
 * @return Media
 */
public function setUpdateAt($updateAt)
{
    $this->updateAt = $updateAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updateAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdateAt()
{
    return $this->updateAt;
}
```

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: It is completely unclear what you do and when do you get an error. In any case the stacktrace could give you an idea where error happens.

Comment: This error appear when i upload my image.. its hard for me to explain un english, im sorry for this. I think i have missed something in my configuration, because on another computer this work fine. Il like a dog in a cockpit, i dont understand what im doing lol

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please add "**'mapped' => false,**" to form builder.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
   ->add('file', FileType::class, 
     array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'mapped' => false,            
    ))
    ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ;
 }
```

Those who say that it is wrong to dissolve, see the test there. I'm not the one who made it wrong.

Test code:
https://github.com/symfony/property-access/blob/master/Tests/PropertyAccessorCollectionTest.php#L151

A second solution is to add **function setXxx** to the property that gives an error in **class Entity**.

```
public $xxx;

public function setXxx(Array $xxx)
{
    $this->xxx = $xxx;
}
```

Or

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->xxx = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Video Link: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/create-genus-note

My English is bad, I can tell you.

Comment: Remove the error but not correct. The entity is mapped, the problem is not there

Comment: Gauthier, Do you have a solution?

Comment: No, not yet ... Still looking for a solution. I saw someone with the same issue, and he solved it by initialising a new ArrayCollection : $this->val = new ArrayCollection(); in the constructor. But it is not my case

Comment: The 2nd solution helped me to realise that I'd changed a property from a collection to a single entity (authors to author) and not cleaned up my class. Thanks!

Comment: FYI in case it helps anyone, in my case, I was missing the removeXxx() method... so when removing from the list it threw this error...

Comment: A setter is the only valid response.

Answer (score 7):

Setting mapped => false is not the real solution, because the field IS mapped to the entity.

In my case, I have a OneToMany relation, so I need the field mapped in order to use the 'cascase' => {"all"} option.

If the field is not mapped, then you must to persist the related entity manually. That's no good.

Comment: 'mapped' => false, I solved the problem like this, your problem may be different.

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled on this while searching solution for my problem, that was shooting the same error and I was using also ArrayCollection class, so this may be helpful to someone:

My field in ArrayCollection is called `$files`, so I had to add constructor like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Then I added add and remove methods, like this:

```
public function addFile(MyFile $file) : self
{
    $file->setParentMyItem($this); // Setting parent item 
    $this->files->add($file);
    return $this;
}

public function removeFile(MyFile $file) : self
{
    $this->files->removeElement($file);
    return $this;
}
```

But catch is that even my field name was `$files` I had to name `add` and `remove` methods `addFile()` and `removeFile()`, without 's' at end, which is totally not logical to me, but that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happened because I had an entity property but the getter/setters were missing. I used:

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate MyBundle\\Entity\\MyEntity`

to regenerate them

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me but on a OneToMany relation. Although setting "mapped => false" also solved the error there is another option. I only had a getter, adder and remover method on the entity. I needed to add a "setter" too

In my case it was:

```
/**
 * @param ArrayCollection|SubStatusOptions[]
 */
public function setSubStatusOptions(ArrayCollection $subStatusOptions)
{
    $this->subStatusOptions = $subStatusOptions;
}
```