# Could not determine access type for property "tags"

Tags: doctrine-orm, tags, symfony

I've the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246686/embed-a-collection-of-forms-error-could-not-determine-access-type-for-property?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I used Demo code to change under my project... and I've a problem with News<->Tags
The error is always the same - Could not determine access type for property "tags"
I changed the mappedBy and inversedBy annotations and nothing helped me.
If I make changes by hand in database all is looking fine. I use MySQL.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="tags")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="news_tag")
 */
private $news;

public function addNews(News $news)
{
    $this->news[] = $news;
```

---

```
/**
 * @var Tag[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="news", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name": "ASC"})
 * @Assert\Count(max="5", maxMessage="Too many tags. Maximum is 5")
 */
private $tags; public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();

public function addTags(Tag $tag)
{
    $tag->addNews($this);
    $this->tags[] = $tag;
}

/**
 * Remove tag
 *
 * @param Tag $tag
 */
public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

Comment: I think the question you've linked to might be a duplicate - I've added an answer there that I think would be applicable here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed a Collection of Forms Error: Could not determine access type for property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246686/embed-a-collection-of-forms-error-could-not-determine-access-type-for-property)