# Symfony form hidden relation to foreign entity

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-3.1

I am trying to create a form in symfony 3. It has a hidden field for a relation to another entity. It is defined as

```
$builder->add('course', HiddenType::class, array('property_path' => 'course.id'))
```

Doing so when i submit the form i get an error, because the id property is not visible and there's no setter obviously.

```
Could not determine access type for property "id".
```

What should i do? Adding a setter for id would probably be a bad idea. There's a reason why there is none by default. Other fields than the id are not unique so i cannot use any of those.

I guess one option might be a custom type, that queries the database for the referring entity. But is there a simpler way for this pretty standard use case?

**Edit**

Okay obviously my question was misunderstood. So i'll explain better. It's not about Doctrine. My Datamodel is fine, the field is a proper relation and not something else. The problem is only about the Symfony Form component, specifically that `HiddenField` seemingly cannot handle a relation by default. First it would result in an error upon display of the Form `Cannot serialize type Model to string`, which i can solve with the `property_path` directive for the display of the form. But once it is submitted it cannot create the related entity because it cannot set the id property (see the `property_path`) of the related doctrine entity.

A working solution is to use a `DataTransformerInterface` class instead of something like the property path. But one must implement one for every entity needed. So i was wondering if there was a easier solution because it seemed to me to be a pretty standard usecase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not determine access type for property "file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213014/could-not-determine-access-type-for-property-file)

Comment: why you are using property_path? Field 'course' should be mapped to other entity - then value in your hidden field will be ID of that foreign entity.

Comment: @AndrzejPiszczek Probably thats what i missed in the docs. Is there an option for that? Currently i am using a custom transformer

Comment: read http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html . There are information about entity connection.

Comment: Okay then you missunderstood me. Doctrine connections are fine and they are working. I just don't know about the form component (it is working btw but i wonder if there is a simpler solution)

Comment: I think it would be helpful explain your data model better. It's not clear why you wouldn't just have a relationship like OneToMany (or ManyToOne, or whatever appropriate). If you did this you wouldn't need anything like what you are doing.

Comment: Obviously i was misunderstood. The property is a proper relationship. See my edit

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @RodrigoFerrari i posted an answer on what i did to overcome this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i did:

I used a `Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface` on the field, to serialize the model and then upon form transmission load it again from the database via doctrine. Probably not what everybody wants in every case and also means the form needs the entity manager as an option.

In the form

```
/**
 * Some form
 */
class SomeType extends AbstractType
{
    // Configure 
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        [...]
        $resolver->setRequired('entity_manager');
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('course', HiddenType::class);

        [...]

        $builder->get('course')
           ->addModelTransformer(new CourseTransformer($options['entity_manager']));
    }
}
```

And here is the CourseTransformer

```
class CourseTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    // The object manager
    private $manager;

    //Constructor
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (course) to a string (id).
     */
    public function transform($course)
    {
        if (null === $course) return '';
        return $course->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (id) to an object (course).
     */
    public function reverseTransform($courseId)
    {
        // no course id? It's optional, so that's ok
        if (!$courseId) {
            return;
        }

        $course = $this->manager
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:Course')
            // query for the issue with this id
            ->find($courseId)
        ;

        if (null === $course) {
            // causes a validation error
            // this message is not shown to the user
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'An course with id "%s" does not exist!',
                $courseId
            ));
        }

        return $course;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Symfony 4 approach**

You need to create a DataTransformer class for your entity, this class will tell Symfony how to serialize your entity when rendering it as a string, for example as a hidden input.

This is how I do it:

First, I create a folder "DataTransformer" inside the "Form" folder, and inside I create my entity DataTransformer class.

Your class must implement DataTransformerInterface and the two methods: transform and reverseTransform. You can read more about those methods in the PHPDoc in the interface class.

This is a working example of a DataTransformer class.

```
<?php


namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;


use App\Repository\CompetitionRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class CompetitionTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    private $repository;

    public function __construct(CompetitionRepository $repository) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($competition): ?int
    {
        return ( $competition !== null ) ? $competition->getId() : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function reverseTransform($competitionId)
    {

        if ('' === $competitionId || null === $competitionId) {
            return '';
        }

        $competition = $this->repository->find( $competitionId );
        return $competition;
    }
}
```

You will use the DataTransformer class in your form ass follow.

```
class EventType extends AbstractType
{
    [...]
    private $competitionRepository;

    public function __construct(CompetitionRepository $competitionRepository)
    {
        $this->competitionRepository = $competitionRepository;
    }

    [...]

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        [...]
        // This is how you use your DataTransformer class
        $builder->add('competition', HiddenType::class);
        $builder->get('competition')->addModelTransformer(new CompetitionTransformer( $this->competitionRepository ));
    }

    [...]
}
```